# How to align a python output

Tags: python, alignment

I'm having some data stored in the SQL database table. I need to fetch all that data from the DB and print it as a python output in a human-readable format like an aligned table.

Below you can see I used `fetchall()` method to fetch those data and used `print` statement with 2 `for` loops.

```
#executing all the records in the SQL query 
cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM game_log")

#Fetch results using fetchall() method
data=cursor.fetchall()

print("\n\nDate&Time\t\tName\tWord\tTurns Given\tTurns Used\tResults")

print("================================================================================")
for item in data:
    for value in item:
        print(value,end="\t")
    print()
```

Below you can see some of them are displaying as aligned but some of the data aren't displaying as aligned.

How to display all the data aligned?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2n1pb.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a dataframe with Pandas from your data and then print it:

```
import pandas as pd

column_names = ["Date&Time", "Name", "Word", "Turns Given", "Turns Used", "Results"]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data, columns = column_names)
print(df)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm still learning python as a beginner. Your answer is clear. Again thank you for your time.<3

Answer (score 0):

Use python f string with formatting like this:

```
>>> print(f'{2.2:10.2f}')
      2.20
>>> print(f'{2.2:10.1f}')
       2.2
```

check this for reference: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings

Comment: Thank you for helping me and thank you for your time.<3

Answer (score 0):

You can compute the maximum width of each column (including the widths of headings) and use a format string to ensure that all columns print the same width:

```
data = [ ["05/12/2021_20:12","kamal","football",8,8,"Lost"],
         ["05/12/2021_20:14","amal","australia",9,2,"Lost"]]

headings = ["Date&Time","Name","Word","Turns Given","Turns Used","Results"]
widths   = [max(map(len,map(str,col))) for col in zip(headings,*data)]

print(*(f"{c:<{w}}" for c,w in zip(headings,widths)))
print("="*sum(widths,len(widths)-1))
for row in data:
    print(*(f"{c:<{w}}" for c,w in zip(row,widths)))
```

Output:

```
Date&Time        Name  Word      Turns Given Turns Used Results
===============================================================
05/12/2021_20:12 kamal football  8           8          Lost   
05/12/2021_20:14 amal  australia 9           2          Lost
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I'm still learning Python as a beginner. Your answer is also clear. Thank you for your time.<3